# Error IllegalAnnotationsException al imprimir XML

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Al imprimir en xml los datos *(`nombrep` y `especialidad`)* de la clase `Profesor` me sale el error de que tiene dos propiedades con el mismo nombre "`especialidad`" y otras dos con "`nombrep`".

¿Alguien sabe por que?

Este es mi código:

```
@XmlRootElement()
public class Profesor {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private String nombrep;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String apellidos;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String dni;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String especialidad;

    //CONSTRUCTOR

    public Profesor(String nombrep, String apellidos, String dni, String especialidad) {
        this.nombrep = nombrep;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
        this.dni = dni;
        this.especialidad = especialidad;
    }
    public Profesor() {}
    public String getNombrep() { return nombrep; }
    public String getApellidos() { return apellidos;  }
    public String getDni() {return dni; }
    public String getEspecialidad() { return especialidad;}
    @XmlElement(name = "Nombre_profesor")
    public void setNombrep(String nombrep) { this.nombrep = nombrep; }
    public void setAutor(String apellidos) { this.apellidos = apellidos; }
    public void setEditorial(String dni) { this.dni = dni; } 
    public void setEspecialidad(String especialidad) {  this.especialidad = especialidad;  }
}
```

Detalles de la excepción:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of
>   IllegalAnnotationExceptions La clase tiene dos propiedades con el
>   mismo nombre "especialidad"   this problem is related to the following
>   location:         at public java.lang.String
>   generated.Profesor.getEspecialidad()      at generated.Profesor this
>   problem is related to the following location:         at protected
>   java.lang.String generated.Profesor.especialidad      at
>   generated.Profesor

Comment: Hola @Juan, podrías subir parte del código de error para que podamos ver como te ayudamos.

Comment: Si, ya está subido!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como no le has "anotado" cómo se debe acceder a los campos, el sistema de anotaciones se lía con las dos opciones.

Prueba a poner a la clase la siguiente anotación:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement()
public class Profesor {
    ...
```

De este modo debería ignorar el *setter* y *getter*.

Comment: Genial ya no me sale el error! Ahora me aparece otro de unmarsal al leer el xml en esta linea: Universidad miUniversidad2 = (Universidad) unmars.unmarshal(new FileReader("c:\\temporal\\universidad.xml"));

Comment: Eso sería otra pregunta... créala